# Error while integrating twitter

Tags: android, twitter, twitter-oauth, twitter4j, socialauth

I'm new to this twitter integration and I've tried twitter integration in two different ways one with social auth and other with twitter core 4j

Social auth works fine with TAB 2 but doesn't work at all for N8000 and twitter core 4j gives error in getting access token and the example [here](http://www.androidhive.info/2012/09/android-twitter-oauth-connect-tutorial/) takes me to a webView saying error accessing ouath.

Could someOne help me in giving the best example for twitter integration which works fine and other devices

Note : I've followed every step to generate consumer key and other keys

---

```
static String TWITTER_CONSUMER_KEY = "nAIxYApY73kBKXPVDuM0A"; 
static String TWITTER_CONSUMER_SECRET = "lB3OCl9E0uJR4yoWBugZGrsHJ9HfKWCTv9ZAzJFsjc"; 
static String PREFERENCE_NAME = "twitter_oauth";
static final String PREF_KEY_OAUTH_TOKEN = "oauth_token";
static final String PREF_KEY_OAUTH_SECRET = "oauth_token_secret";
static final String PREF_KEY_TWITTER_LOGIN = "isTwitterLogedIn";
static final String TWITTER_CALLBACK_URL = "oauth://t4jsample";
static final String URL_TWITTER_AUTH = "auth_url";
static final String URL_TWITTER_OAUTH_VERIFIER = "oauth_verifier";
static final String URL_TWITTER_OAUTH_TOKEN = "oauth_token";
```

Comment: http://www.files.com/shared/51c2881be8c25/TwiiterAPINewAPI.zip try this example

Comment: this gives me a force close as soon as i click login in N8000

Comment: yes first you have to put your consumer key and consumer secret

Comment: on `TwitterHomeActivity` class put your consumer key and secret key here static String TWITTER_CONSUMER_KEY = "PUT YOUR TWITTER_CONSUMER_KEY HERE"; 
 static String TWITTER_CONSUMER_SECRET = "PUT YOUR TWITTER_CONSUMER_SECRET HERE";

Comment: if you don't know how to get consumer key and secret key than look at twitter official site https://dev.twitter.com/discussions/2530

Comment: Please could u see the answer below and say what are the other changes I have to do

Comment: Are you sure you want to publish your consumer secret…?